# Error converting bytecode to dex IInAppBillingService

Tags: bytecode, dex

When I want to test the application I have an error message :

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;

My build.gradle app :

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "automation.test.application"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 25
        versionName "2.6.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}


dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    api 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    api 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    api 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using `com.android.billingclient:billing` for in-app billing.

If you were using in-app billing with AIDL previously, try removing 'IInAppBillingService.aidl' file from your project.

That should fix your issue.